# Get coordinates from voxels in vtkimagedata

Tags: python, vtk

I am trying to get the coordinates of a `vtkImageData`, but I could not find any method to achieve it. For example, given a `vtkImageData` object, called `image`, I know I can get the voxel values like this:

```
image = vtk.vtkImageData()
voxels = image.GetPointData().GetScalars()
```

Is there a method that would return the coordinates of a particular voxel or the coordinates of all the voxels? For example, considering 3D image, if in `voxels` there are 3 voxel values, I would get the coordinates of those voxels, like in a list, e.g.:

```
[[12,120,3],[14,20,3][119, 34, 3]]
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Code below will loop through all values within a 3D volume and extract the values, look at ScalarPointer and GetScalarComponent in the documentation for further help

```
x_dim, y_dim, z_dim = image.GetDimensions()

for x in xrange(x_dim):
    for y in xrange(x_dim):
        for z in xrange(x_dim):
            val = image.GetScalarComponentAsFloat(x,y,z)
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `ComputeStructuredCoordinates` could meet your dem